# Preserve alphabetical order in index when the entry has a TikZ code

Tags: tikz-pgf, indexing

Friends, as a follow up to [Overlapping TikZ nodes to look as a tape strip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23090), I added a TikZ code to an index entry using the `splitidx`package. Consider this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[useindex]{splitidx}

\newindex[Index of Foo]{iof}

\makeindex

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,backgrounds}

\usepackage{xstring}

\tikzset{
    tape node/.style={
        on chain,
        draw,
        inner sep=1pt,
        outer xsep=0pt,
        minimum height=0.2cm,
        minimum width=0.2cm
    }
}

\newcommand*\myblackbox[1]{%
    \node[
        tape node
    ] {\tiny\tt\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{#1}};
}

\newcommand*\mygraybox[1]{%
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \node[
            tape node,
            gray!60
        ] {\color{gray!60}\tiny\tt\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{#1}};        \end{pgfonlayer}
}

\DeclareRobustCommand*\drawboxes[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        start chain=going right,
        node distance=0pt
    ]
    \IfSubStr{#1}{A}{\myblackbox{A}}{\mygraybox{A}}%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{N}{\myblackbox{N}}{\mygraybox{N}}%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{C}{\myblackbox{C}}{\mygraybox{C}}%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{Q}{\myblackbox{Q}}{\mygraybox{Q}}%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{P}{\myblackbox{P}~}{\mygraybox{P}~}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\sindex[iof]{\drawboxes{AC} Oranges}
\sindex[iof]{\drawboxes{ANCQ} Grapes}
\sindex[iof]{\drawboxes{CP} Bananas}
\sindex[iof]{\drawboxes{Q} Avocado}
\sindex[iof]{\drawboxes{P} Strawberry}

\printindex*

\end{document}
```

It works like a charm, but unfortunately, due to the TikZ code added to the beginning of the entry, the alphabetical order is lost:

[image: List of foo]

I have a wild guess: by passing some regular expression pattern to the `splitindex` parser tool, I could somehow make the generated index ignore the TikZ code at the beginning of the entry.

If possible, I'd like to stick with the `splitidx` package, as it can handle several indices I have in the document. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's standard **makeindex** syntax:

```
\sindex[iof]{Oranges@\drawboxes{AC} Oranges}
\sindex[iof]{Grapes@\drawboxes{ANCQ} Grapes}
\sindex[iof]{Bananas@\drawboxes{CP} Bananas}
\sindex[iof]{Avocado@\drawboxes{Q} Avocado}
\sindex[iof]{Strawberry@\drawboxes{P} Strawberry}
```

Comment: Fantastic, egreg! I had no idea of this syntax. Thanks!